# Why is my Python Altair chart printing a blank line?

Tags: python, pandas, matlab, matplotlib

Wondering if anyone can help me understand why python altair chart is not printing...

I’m only seeing this when I run the code:

[image]

It literally isn’t outputting anything.

This is what my chart looks like converted to_dict; recommended for troubleshooting to ensure you have data.

[image]

Any ideas about why it’s not displaying a graph/chart/etc, and only printing a blank line?

Adding the head of the csv in pandas form.

[image]

Comment: It may be helpful if you post more of your code and/or a sample of your data.  Have you already added `%matplotlib inline` at the top of your notebook?  This enables matplotlib figures to be shown inline.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @zachdj. I just added "%matplotlib inline" at the top and it still didn't work. I did think that was necessary since I'm trying to display a Altair chart and not a matplotlib graph.

Comment: I've never used Altair before, and mistakenly assumed that it was using matplotlib as a backend (similar to seaborn).

It looks like you've already enabled the notebook renderer.  Do you have `vega` installed in the environment running your notebook?

Comment: No worries. I think that might be it.

I have it installed on my system, but apparently not enabled for the notebook.  Any ideas about the following error?

When I run this command:

`sudo jupyter nbextension enable --sys-prefix vega`

I keep getting the following error :

`OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/etc'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was enabling the vega module/extension in the notebook. Installing it is only half the battle, then you must enable it. :)

`sudo jupyter-nbextension enable vega --py --user`